# Java Spring framework intranet-application exporting

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, export

I am just beginning to write an intranet based application using Spring framework. Wanted the following suggestions and clarifications.

1) Can i convert my project as an exe and deploy in neighbouring system?
2) If i can do that, should the neighbouring system also have tomcat and java installed or we can have the installer embedded in the exe?

Kindly share your inputs and oblige.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Can i convert my project as an exe and deploy in neighbouring system?

No, Java does not use EXE.  That would break the "write once, run anywhere" paradigm as not all OSes use .EXE files.  For instance **Linux**, OS X, FreeBSD, etc, etc.  MSDOS and MS Windows are the only OSes that "officially" support .EXE.  Linux and other *nix based systems can run things to allow them to simulate enough of the Windows/DOS system to run them, but results are varied.

What you probably want to do is package your app as either a WAR or an EAR.  A WAR, or "Web Archive" is a Java package for web applications, and has some specific files you must put in specific places in addition to your JARs (or "Java Archive") for your app and libs.  It makes your web app portable (somewhat).  You can read all about WAR specifications by Google'ing.

An EAR, or "Enterprise Archive" is pretty much just a collection of WARs.  At least in my realm of influence we don't really use EAR deployments often.

If you are already deploying to Tomcat, they you probably already have a WAR deployment.  To move it to another system, you should be able to simply install Java and Tomcat and put the WAR in the appropriate deploy folder (I think it's actually called "deploy" in Tomcat).

Another alternative would be to use the new Spring Boot stuff to create an app with either embedded Tomcat or embedded Jetty in a self-executing JAR.  You still need a JVM to run it, but the web app server piece (either Tomcat or Jetty) would run as an embedded server.  Check out Spring Boot [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).  It doesn't take much to port over a WAR to be a stand-alone Spring Boot application, in my opinion.

> 2) If i can do that, should the neighbouring system also have tomcat and java installed or we can have the installer embedded in the exe?

You will need Java installed (a JVM, either the JRE or JDK would suffice) and Tomcat (or some other web app container/server).  You would deploy it the same way you are deploying it on your test server.  That is unless you plan to package it as a Spring Boot application, in which case you would only need the Java JVM installed as mentioned above.